# DropDownList for Foreign key does not return value to Create Function

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, foreign-keys, html-helper

I have three tables as follows:

```
public class A {
    public int A_ID {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class B {
    public int B_ID {get;set;}
    ...
}

public class C {
    public int A_ID {get;set;}
    public int C_B_ID {get;set;}
    ...

    public virtual A a {get;set;}
    public virtual B b {get;set;}
}
```

I have the following keys set up:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.a)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(u => u.A_ID);

modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
                    .HasRequired(x => x.b)
                    .WithMany()
                    .HasForeignKey(u => u.C_B_ID);

modelBuilder.Entity<C>()
             .Property(t => t.A_ID)
                .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None);
```

On the Create View page i have these dropdown lists for the foreign keys:

```
<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.A_ID, "A")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("A_ID", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.A_ID)
</div>

<div class="editor-label">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.C_B_ID, "B")
</div>
<div class="editor-field">
    @Html.DropDownList("C_B_ID", String.Empty)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.C_B_ID)
</div>
```

This is my create function:

```
//
    // GET: /C/Create

    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewBag.A_ID = new SelectList(db.As, "A_ID", "Name");
        ViewBag.B_ID = new SelectList(db.Bs, "B_ID", "Name");
        return View();
    }
//
//POST

public ActionResult Create(C c_instance)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            db.Cs.Add(c_instance);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        ViewBag.A_ID = new SelectList(db.As, "A_ID", "Name", c_instance.A_ID);
       ****EDITED***  ViewBag.B_ID = new SelectList(db.Bs, "B_ID", "Name", c_instance.C_B_ID);
        return View(c_instance);
    }
```

Now, in the create function, I receive the value selected in the first dropdown for A_ID but the dropdown value for C_B_ID always comes as zero. This causes this problem:

```
The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint
"FK_dbo.Cs_dbo.Bs_C_B_ID". 
The conflict occurred in database "C:\temp.MDF", table "dbo.Bs", column 'B_ID'.
The statement has been terminated.
```

Now, this is happening because C_instance.A_ID has the correct A_ID selected from the dropdownlist but C_instance.C_B_ID = 0 at all times! (And the dropdownlist does show me all the entries in table Bs, and i select one of them)

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass your list to the `DropDownList` helper.

```
@Html.DropDownList("A_ID", ViewBag.A_ID, String.Empty)
@Html.DropDownList("C_B_ID", ViewBag.B_ID, String.Empty)
```

Comment: sorry, i made a small mistake in my post.. please see the updated post. i have also added the get method

Comment: @Strangeloop Did you update the view because it still doesn't look like you are passing the list into the `DropDownList` helper.

Comment: Thanks AsymptoticFault, i looked at the GET: Create function and realized what was wrong!

All I had to do is change


    public ActionResult Create()
    {
       ...
        ** CORRECTION** ViewBag.C_B_ID = new SelectList(db.Bs, "B_ID", "Name");
        return View();
    }
   
    public ActionResult Create(C c_instance)
    {
       ...
       ...
       ****CORRECTION***  ViewBag.C_B_ID = new SelectList(db.Bs, "B_ID", "Name", c_instance.C_B_ID);
        return View(c_instance);
    }
}

Comment: You're welcome, glad I was able to help even though it wasn't the answer I suggested :P  Your solution is interesting though because I did not know the helpers would inspect the ViewBag as well when you pass a string name to them, I thought they would just check the Model for a property of that name.

Comment: i am surprised myself. but then i have learnt not to trust any auto-generated code especially anything related to microsoft :D